# Ubuntu freezes for a while

Tags: 20.04

PC Configurations

1. Motherboard - Asrock - M3A770DE
2. Processor - AMD Phenom II X6 1045T
3. RAM 4 strips of 4 GB
4. Unit at 600W
5. GTS 250
6. Seagate Barracuda 160 GB (7200rmp) HDD

P.s. There are no systems other than Ubuntu

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu and every time I search for something on the Internet or create a folder and try to change it, the system freezes for 5 seconds, maybe more. if you monitor the processor in real time, you can see how one or two cores rise to 100%.

When I installed the system for the first time there were no such problems, maybe I reinstalled incorrectly?

Comment: When the core(s) rise to 100%, check what processes (in System Monitor) are using it.